# How to add css-class active for menu items by using just javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I tried to add "active class" which will change the color of the navigation item (displayed through li tags) when user clicks on it. To do this, I make a function to remove active class if there is any in all li elements. After that, when there is a click on navi item, I will add the active class to that element.
The problem is that when running my code, instead of just one item has "active" class, all items have.
I found many solutions for this problem, but most of them use jQuery which I have no knowledge about the library.
I hope someone can point my code errors below.
Thank you!

```
// Find all li tags
const liTags = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// Function to remove the current element has active class
function RemoveActive() {
    for (let i = 0; i < liTags.length; i++) {
        const currentActiveClass = document.querySelector('.active');
        // Remove active class in the current li element
        if (currentActiveClass != null) {
            liTags[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    }   
}

// Add the active class to the clicked item
for (let i = 0; i < liTags.length; i++) {
    liTags[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        RemoveActive;
        liTags[i].classList.add('active');
    })
}
```

Comment: are you trying to make something like radio button ? where only 1 item can be selected among all ?

Comment: Regardless of whatever caused the malfunction rethink the entire approach. Right now **every LI element** available downwards the `document` level at query time features its own click handling. And even though one can do that (instead of event delegation) a much bigger question arises. Is there just one un/ordered list in the entire document? If not, be aware that the current approach will work across the *active* states of different lists ... means, any item click from within a random list removes the `active` class name (if it exists) of any other list item from other lists as well.

Comment: they are all what i need. I learned a lot from you guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error was RemoveActive; where it should have been RemoveActive(), but thought I'd take the time to refactor the code.

I would advise using camel case for the function names removeActive() and name them a more descriptive name than "RemoveActive" as it will make it easier for future development / to understand what this function does as the program grows.

```
const navigationItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

function toggleActiveNavItem() {
  navigationItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
      addClickEventToNavigation(item)
    }
  }
}

function addClickEventToNavigation(item) {
  // Remove active from every navigation item
  navigationItems.forEach(individualNavigationItem =>{
    // Other than the one passed to the function as having been clicked
    if (individualNavigationItem != item) {
      individualNavigationItem.classList.remove("active");
    }

    // If the clicked item does not have the active class, add it
    if (!item.classList.contains("active")) {
      individualNavigationItem.classList.add("active");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from my example, i add `classList.contains` instead of check element then you have a typo error `()` into function

```js
// Find all li tags
const liTags = document.querySelectorAll('li');

function RemoveActive() {
    for (let i = 0; i < liTags.length; i++) {
        if (liTags[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            liTags[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    }   
}

for (let i = 0; i < liTags.length; i++) {
    liTags[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        RemoveActive();
        liTags[i].classList.add('active');
    })
}
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of use `remove` and `add` you can use `toggle` like:

```js
// Find all li tags
const liTags = document.querySelectorAll('li');

function RemoveActive() {
  const li = document.querySelector('li.active')
  if (li) {
    li.classList.toggle("active");
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < liTags.length; i++) {
  liTags[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    RemoveActive();
    liTags[i].classList.toggle('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should follow this practice for clean and less code

```js
var root = document.querySelector(".root")

root.addEventListener("click",e=>{
  var t = e.target,
      li = t.closest("li")
  if(li){
    root.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(each=>each.classList.remove("active")) 
    li.classList.add("active")
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}

.root li {
  padding:2px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="root">
  <li class="active">items</li>
  <li>items</li>
  <li>items</li>
  <li>items</li>
  <li>items</li>
  <li>items</li>
  <li>items</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is quite difficult for me. I think I need to learn step by step.

Answer (score 0):

From the above direct comment on the OP's question ...

> *"Regardless of whatever caused the malfunction rethink the entire approach. Right now **every LI element** available downwards the `document` level at query time features its own click handling. And even though one can do that (instead of event delegation) a much bigger question arises. Is there just one un/ordered list in the entire document? If not, be aware that the current approach will work across the *active* states of different lists ... means, any item click from within a random list removes the `active` class name (if it exists) of any other list item from other lists as well."*

The next following example is for demonstration purposes only in order to show what can be achieved with an [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) based approach ...

```js
function getNestedListRoot(listNode) {
  let elmNode = listNode;
  while (listNode = listNode?.parentNode.closest('ol, ul')) {
    elmNode = listNode;
  }
  return elmNode;
}

function handleNestedListItemsActiveState({ target }) {
  // the LI element closest to the `click` source.
  const srcLiElm = target.closest('li');

  // guard
  if (srcLiElm === null) {
    return;
  }
  // the LI element's un/ordered list parent.
  const listNode = srcLiElm.parentNode;
  // the top most un/ordered list node
  // of a nested list structure.
  const listRoot = getNestedListRoot(listNode);

  listRoot
    .querySelectorAll('li')
    .forEach(elmNode =>
      // de'active'ate every LI element
      // within the nested list structure.
      elmNode.classList.remove('active')
    );
  let liElm = srcLiElm;

  while (liElm) {
    // follow the path of directly nested
    // LI elements from the current inner to the
    // most outer LI element and 'active'ate each.    
    liElm.classList.add('active');

    liElm = liElm.parentNode.closest('li');
  }
}

function initialize() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('ol, ul')
    .forEach(elmNode =>
      elmNode.addEventListener('click', handleNestedListItemsActiveState)
    )
}
initialize();
```

```css
body { margin: -2px 0 0 0; }
ol, ul { margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
ol ul, ul ol, ol ol, ul ul { margin: 0; }
li { margin: 0 0 0 -20px; font-size: 12px; }
li.active,
li.active li.active { color: #fc0; }
li.active li { color: initial; }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="active">
    OL_A-a
    <ul>
      <li>
        OL_A-a__UL_A-a
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        OL_A-a__UL_A-b
        <ol>
          <li>
            OL_A-a__UL_A-b__OL_B-a
          </li>
          <li>
            OL_A-a__UL_A-b__OL_B-b
          </li>
          <li class="active">
            OL_A-a__UL_A-b__OL_B-c
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        OL_A-a__UL_A-c
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    OL_A-b
  </li>
  <li>
    OL_A-c
    <ul>
      <li>
        OL_A-c__UL_B-a
      </li>
      <li>
        OL_A-c__UL_B-b
      </li>
      <li>
        OL_A-c__UL_B-c
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>

<ol>
  <li>
    OL_A-a
    <ul>
      <li>
        OL_A-a__UL_A-a
      </li>
      <li>
        OL_A-a__UL_A-b
        <ol>
          <li>
            OL_A-a__UL_A-b__OL_B-a
          </li>
          <li>
            OL_A-a__UL_A-b__OL_B-b
          </li>
          <li>
            OL_A-a__UL_A-b__OL_B-c
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        OL_A-a__UL_A-c
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    OL_A-b
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    OL_A-c
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        OL_A-c__UL_B-a
      </li>
      <li>
        OL_A-c__UL_B-b
      </li>
      <li>
        OL_A-c__UL_B-c
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```